# methods like find() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

with find() method in laravel you can search and find by primary key which is id by default.
I need method that give all instance of Blog model with same tag

```
    public function blog($tag)
{

    $table = Blog::where('tag', $tag)->get();
    return view('Blog',[
         'blogs'=>$table
    ]);

}
```

and this is my model detail

```
    Schema::create('blogs', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->text('pics');
        $table->string('tag');

    });
```

I used dd('$table') to see results 
result was empty

```
    Collection {#175 ▼
    #items: []
             }
```

Comment: And whats the question?

Comment: What is the result when you use the where method?

Comment: @tkausl nothing returns in dd()

Comment: @JoshBolton result added to question

Comment: @RezaSamkhanian you got empty collection because there is no any row where `tag = $tag`. Please show some DB data and `dd($tag)` result.

Comment: have you data in db?

Comment: I added two instance of Blog and call blog with  pageController@blog/{"tag1"}
I doubt maybe I should send String to blog in different way 
@AlexeyMezenin

Comment: @RezaSamkhanian if you want help, you should post real data here. Noone will be able to help you without seeing `$tag` value and real DB data.

Comment: can you try to pass $tag as dd('$tag'),?
at start of your method

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some possible problems:

1. no data in db
2. tags - if you added some blogs - are truncated during save
3. you have model binding for route, and `tag1` is binded to model, so using it with `where` clause causes no results when you use `get` method.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is OK with your query.

Make sure your `$tag` variable contains real tag which is set in Blog entry.